# Формат ячеек в сводной таблице

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

Как задать числовой формат ячеек в сводной таблице?

Answer (score 1):

Оказалось достаточно чтобы в таблице-источнике был числовой формат ячеек. Сводная таблица сама подхватывает нужный формат.